# How to remove default superscript from gtsummary table column headers?

Tags: header, gtsummary, superscript, gt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAW6E.png)
gtsummary creates column headers with a superscript of 1 when we use variables in the superscript. Is there a way to disable this?

I've tried using exponential = FALSE, but that doesn't seem to work with tbl_reg_summary(). I also need to remove the superscript "1" on the first line of the foot note. This is the table I'm trying to create

```
 dm_shell <-  dm %>% 
  select(-USUBJID) %>% 

mutate(AGEGR1 = factor(AGEGR1, levels = c("18 - < 65", "65 - < 75", "> = 75"))) %>% 

  tbl_reg_summary(
    digits = everything() ~  style_xxx,
    by = TRTPG4,
    hide_n = TRUE,
    #type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    #stat_fns = everything() ~ my_stats
    exponential = FALSE,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}","{mean}({sd})","{median}","{min},{max}","{N_miss}")
  ) %>% 

  add_overall(last = TRUE, col_label = "All Patients") %>%

  bold_labels() %>%

  modify_header(
    list(
      all_stat_cols(stat_0 = FALSE) ~ "**{level}**  \n (N=xx)",
      stat_0 ~ "**All Patients**  \n (N=xx)"
    ))  %>%

  add_stat_label(label = AGE ~ c("N","Mean (SD)","Median","Min,Max", "Missing")) %>% 

  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Date of Data Cut: DD-MONTH NAME-YY, N = number of patients in each group; n = number of patients with data available;percentages are based on N.\n")
```

I didn't not find any sources online that can resolve the problem.

Comment: There is an example here on the gtsummary website: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#add_difference

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response. Can you point me to the exact line of code? I've tried using exponential = FALSE, but that doesn't seem to work with tbl_reg_summary()

Comment: `modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)`

Comment: That does not solve the question. can you please recheck?